# Is it safe for a nodejs module to refer to variables outside its root directory?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Let's say I have my nodejs application `foobar-base`, and I have created another application (`foobar-baz`) that is intended to be a "module" to `foobar-base`:

```
$ cd foobar-base
$ npm install foobar-baz
```

Is it bad practice if a method in `foobar-baz` depended on a class I have defined in `foobar-base`?

That is:

#### foobar-base/node_modules/foobar-baz/index.js

```
var myClass = require('../../src/myClass.js');
myClass.myMethod();
```

It is *possible* to do it, although if I am testing the module via `npm link`:

```
$ cd foobar-baz
$ npm link
$ cd ../foobar-base
$ npm link foobar-baz
```

Then the `require` call fails, as `../../` now points to `/usr/lib/node_modules/`, at least on my machine. But theoretically, when published into npm, the require would work.

So this kind of unexpected (yet understandable) behaviour is throwing enough red flags for me to not consider following this course of action.

Instead, I've just "globalised" `myClass`:

#### foobar-base/node_modules/foobar-baz/index.js

```
myClass.myMethod();    // already available, see below
```

#### foobar-base/index.js

```
myClass = require('./src/myClass');

var foobar-baz = require('foobar-baz');    // myClass.myMethod() is called
```

... but then again, "globals are bad"... so what should I do?

Comment: you should require foobar-baz from foobar-base .. and not in reverse, foobar-base is supposed to be the `base` and `baz` supposed to be part of it

Comment: Modules should never have cyclical dependencies.  If they need to depend on each other, they belong in the same module, not as 2 separate ones.